# how to convert local variable to attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I have a cucumber feature file (login.feature) with:

```
When I login with invalid credentials
```

The corresponding step definition (in login_steps.rb) as:

```
When(/^I login with 'invalid' credentials$/) do
  @page.login(USERS[:invalid]) 
end
```

user.rb under the env folder has:

```
USERS = {
    :valid => {
        :username => "peterpan",
        :password => "xyz"
    },
    :invalid => {
        :username => "invalidusername",
        :password => "testtest"
    }
}
```

The above works perfectly fine.

Now I need few more like valid, validwithusernameonly,validwithpasswordonly etc. For example, the steps:

```
When I login with 'invalid' credentials

When I login with 'valid' credentials

When I login with 'validwithusernameonly' credentials
```

Assume that these credentials are in user.rb

What do I need to do in the step definition below to pass the user_credential_identifier to USERS as mentioned below.

```
When(/^I login with '(.+)' credentials$/) do |user_credential_identifier|
  @page.login(USERS[:invalid])
end
```

Comment: Would you please start with formatting your code? Unformatted code discourages anyone from reading it. Let alone answering it

Comment: @Bala I have done the formatting. Hope it would be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You have captured from the step a string - eg "valid". Since your USERS hash is using symbols as keys, you need to convert the string to a symbol. This can be done by using the `.to_sym` method:

```
user_credential_identifier.to_sym
```

Applying this concept to your step, it would become:

```
When(/^I login with '(.+)' credentials$/) do |user_credential_identifier|
  @page.login(USERS[user_credential_identifier.to_sym])
end
```